# Please help me with regexp_substr in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr

In snowflake below is the regex for seperating strings based on >> but when data is with space it is not doing so I mean it is taking partial value not compete value

```sql
SELECT replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'test1 >> test2 >> test3','([^>]*)([[:space:]]>>[[:space:]]|$)', 1,1 ) , ' >> ','') as test;

SELECT replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'test1 >> test2 >> test3','\\w+([[:space:]]>>[[:space:]]|$)', 1,1) , ' >> ','') as test;
```

I have data like this
'test value >> test1 >> test2'
But above regex is only giving as value but I want complete 'test value'  can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, current results, and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: The 1st RegEx should work as expected.

Comment: It is always good practice to provide sample data and what is desired out out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPLIT_PART is easier to use for this than regular expressions. Here's the example that was giving you trouble:

```
WITH X AS
(SELECT 'test value >> test1 >> test2' as string_to_split)
SELECT 
SPLIT_PART(string_to_split, ' >> ', 1)
, SPLIT_PART(string_to_split, ' >> ', 2)
, SPLIT_PART(string_to_split, ' >> ', 3)
FROM X;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the SPLIT or SPLIT_PART functions? Using regex seems unnecessarily complex for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Split is seperating it in multi rows but my requirement is I should get each value in different column.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to split the string above and the separator is ">>"?

Then you can easily use

1. the split function to create an array with the different "parts" (already mentioned above) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html
2. the split_part function to receive a certain part (already mentioned above) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html
3. the split_to_table function
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html

(Edit: just wanted to send you the references to the documentation)